# How to create a header in Android ListView with two Buttons which run different queries?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Unfortunately, I don't know the correct Android terminology for this type of design:

[image: Android Header ListView]

I have a ListView element in my Android application and depending on which *category* (in the picture above ***NOTES (2)*** and ***LISTS (1)***) is selected, I want to show different results in the ListView.

So, my question is as follows:

How can I extend my ListView in order to make this work? Do I need just two different buttons placed on top, or is there a specific View to use?

Comment: Those are Tabs; you could just load the appropriate data depending on which tab is selected by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to create a Tabbed View. To create a Tabbed View with android material design you can use TabLayout and View Pager.

For each tab you need to create a fragment. like this

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

//Overriden method onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating 
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
}
}
```

see what we are returning inflater.inflate(r.layout.tab1.. 
this is the xml resource file for the tab you want to display.

You also need an adapter for your class that can be implemented using FragmentStatePagerAdapter class.

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

//integer to count number of tabs
int tabCount;

//Constructor to the class 
public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
    super(fm);
    //Initializing tab count
    this.tabCount= tabCount;
}

//Overriding method getItem
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //Returning the current tabs 
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

//Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs 
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
}
```

And at last just implement the tabs in your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

//This is our tablayout
private TabLayout tabLayout;

//This is our viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Adding toolbar to the activity
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
}
```

For more details checkout this tutorial this worked absolutely fine for me. 
[Android TabLayout Example using ViewPager and Fragments](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)

Answer (score 0):

try to use TabLayout, check this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)

Probably the best solution would be to use TabLayout with a ViewPager using two fragments (one for each tab). Check provided link for a comprehensive tutorial